# `is built for` vs `was built for`: how to describe a tool

Tags: differences

We are using a tool and want to report it in our paper. The tool was developed around a year ago for Purpose_X, but we realized it is also very useful for Purpose_Y and used it in the Y project.

Now how shall we report it:

- For Purpose_Y, we used X-Tool (which **is built** for Purpose_X), that generates a high-quality dataset.
- For Purpose_Y, we used X-Tool (which **was built** for Purpose_X), that generates a high-quality dataset

Answer (score 1):

Either one works about equally well. "Was" slightly emphasizes the process of developing it in the past, which is fine. "Is" refers to the tool in the abstract, independent of any point in time — like "a screwdriver is a tool that turns screws." Neither one would make me bat an eye.